# timeBeginPeriod identifier not found error

Tags: c++, windows

When I compile my project I get this error.

```
C:\src\libs\nvrtpaudio\FileRtpSource.
cpp(61) : error C3861: 'timeBeginPeriod': identifier not found
C:\src\libs\nvrtpaudio\FileRtpSource.
cpp(71) : error C3861: 'timeEndPeriod': identifier not found
gmake[5]: *** [_out/win7_x86_debug/FileRtpSource.obj] Error 2
```

I included windows.h but this error still persists. Anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: We can't help you if you don't post the code that produces this error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MSDN [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757624%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Header: Mmsystem.h (include Windows.h)

So you are expected to include "windows.h" and be fine, but what MSDN does not say is that this assumes you don't have `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` defined, which - when defined, and this also can be the case with project created from template - exlcudes "mmsystem.h" you need.

So you have to either make sure you don't have `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` in your project, or otherwise include  directly:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <mmsystem.h> // <<--- Here we go

#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    timeBeginPeriod(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yup. I have LEAN_AND_MEAN defined.